# Type with two enum fields in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, enums, anonymous-types, algebraic-data-types

I have a type that represents a direction, it has an axis and an orientation:

```hs
data Dir = DirX | DirY | DirZ | DirW deriving (Show, Eq)
data Sign = Pos | Neg deriving (Show, Eq)
newtype Direction = Direction (Dir, Sign) deriving (Show, Eq)
```

And that looks kinda overcomplicated. I don't need `Sign` and `Dir` to be distinct types, I just want to pattern match things to their constructors. So is there any nicer way to define such kind of types?

So what I want to do is some kind of

```hs
data Direction = Direction (DirX | DirY | DirZ | DirW) (Pos | Neg) deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Because I do things like `\(Direction _ s) -> if s == Pos then ... else ...`, but I never use `Dir` or `Sign` outside of the `Direction`

I suppose I'm not the first one to ask this, but I really can't figure out how to google this question.

Comment: Well you should not wrap it in a 2-tuple I think, you can use `data Direction = Direction Dir Sign deriving (Show, Eq)`, but nevertheless, I don't really understand what the problem is. If you want the types to be parametric, you can make a parameteric data type, like `data Direction dir sign = Direction dir sign deriving (Eq, Show)`, and then use `Direction Dir Sign` for the ones specific to this.

Comment: I fail to see why you don't need `Sign` and `Dir` to be distinct types. One has 4 possible values, the other 2. Why should they be the same type then? Beyond that, using distinct types will prevent confusion between a direction and a sign, as in passing the wrong value by mistake. I mean, you could simply use `(Int, Int)` and avoid the out-of-range values, but that would be quite fragile, since you'd be making invalid values representable.

Comment: @DEYTD: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think it would help folks offer solutions if you edited your question to add: 1. a small example of your existing code that uses these types, and 2. an example of the kind of code that you would like to be able to write instead. As it stands, it’s somewhat unclear what you want to do.

Comment: I think the question is wishing for a sort of anonymous type. If the only purpose of Sign is as a place to hang constructors that are used in Direction, it's a reasonable thing to wish that you don't have to give it a named type distinct from Direction. But it doesn't really hold up to deep scrutiny, and so Haskell doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: @chi The thing is that's nether the `Sign` or `Dir` is a type that has a limited possible amount of values, `Direction` is. But I think it's a little more convenient to define it as I did, then through 8 distinct constructors.

Comment: `newtype Direction = Direction (Dir, Sign)` or `data Direction = Direction Dir Sign` are more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there's no nicer way.

...then again, personally, I find this way perfectly nice already. So perhaps it is not such a terrible burden to bear.

Of course, there are ways to define completely different types that might still be of interest to you. For example, I have used a direction type along these lines in the past to good effect:

```
data Direction = Direction { x, y, z, w :: Int }
aboutFace (Direction x y z w) = Direction (-x) (-y) (-z) (-w)
-- e is a traditional name from linear algebra for an axis-aligned unit vector
ex = Direction 1 0 0 0
ey = Direction 0 1 0 0
ez = Direction 0 0 1 0
ew = Direction 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pattern synonyms to match values from isomorphic types. Think of `pattern` as the term-level equivalent of `type`. `Bool` is a ready replacement for `Sign`, though there is no convenient 4-way sum type available for `Dir`; you could use `Either Bool Bool` instead.

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

-- type Sign = Bool
-- All two-value types are isomorphic to Bool.
pattern Pos = True
pattern Neg = False

-- type Dir = Either Bool Bool
-- All four-value types are isomorphic to Either Bool Bool
pattern DirX = Left True
pattern DirY = Left False
pattern DirZ = Right True
pattern DirW = Right False

data Direction = Direction Bool (Either Bool Bool)
```

The actual mappings aren't important. This would work just as well if `Pos` were mapped to `False` and `Neg` to `True`, for instance. The important thing is that the mapping is injective.

You can use the patterns for creating values

```
x = Direction Pos DirX
```

and for pattern matching

```
showDir :: Direction -> String
showDir (Direction Pos DirX) = "+X"
-- etc
```

Then

```
> showDir x
"+X"
```

---

In the end, though, I don't think defining `Sign` and `Dir` as distinct types is a problem, though.

Comment: Well, this seems overcomplicated in another direction. Although, defining `Sign` as a `Bool` synonym with patterns for nicer constructor names is very interesting because of built-in functions for booleans. So although you didn't help with my original question this still was helpful. Thanks.